# Existence of a field extension such that for any natural number $n$ ,

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let *$K$* be a field, and $ f_1(x) , f_2(x) , \dots f_n(x) $ $\in$ *$K[x]$* , such that deg *$f_i(x)$*  $\ge 1$ , $1\le i \le n $. I have to show that there exists a field extension *$F/ K$* such that each $f_i(x)$ has a root in *$F$*.

I have no idea from where to start.

Any insight.Thank you.

Comment: Do you understand how to extend a field using $K[x]/(p(x))$ where $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial of $K[x]$?

Comment: Yes, I think $K(\alpha) \simeq K[x]/(p(x)) $ ,where $\alpha$ is a root of $ p(x)=0$ ..am I right ?

Comment: Yes, and $K$ is a subfield of that. Doesn't this suggest an obvious path to your solution?

Comment: Yes, but that's true for one polynomial, what about the others ? I am not getting you clearly,will you please elaborate ?

Comment: You should build a [*tower of fields*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_fields)

Comment: Suppose you have obtained $K(x_1)$ where $x_1$ is some root of irreducible polynomial $f_1$. Now you want adjoin the second root. Take any irreducible polynomial $f_2(y)\in K[x]$ to $K(x_1)[y]$. You will need another variable to depict the second root to be adjoined. Now in this ring, it will have irreducible decomposition and by PID, the irreducibles are maximal. Say $f'_2(y)$ is one of the irreducible. Now consider $K(x_1)[y]/(f'_2(y))$. This gives you a higher extension above $K(x_1)$

Comment: Oh ! I get you now..Thanks for the answer.